# Pair two Bluetooth 5 headphones on iPhone/iPad?

Tags: iphone, audio, bluetooth

In iOS 13 it’s now possible to use an “audio sharing” feature with a second set of AirPods.

But I think I’ve also heard, vaguely, that it’s possible to connect TWO headphones to an iPhone or iPad via Bluetooth 5.

Is this correct? Has anyone been able to do this?